How can I put a microcontroller to sleep after a certain amount of time?
I would like to program my PIC to enter sleep mode after 30 seconds or so of not being active. How can I use a timer or watch dog timer to set a 30 second time count?

Please specify the part number of the PIC you are using.

The approach I usually use is to set up a timer with a repeating interrupt around 4Hz (on recent 8-bit PICs, I have some code using TMR0).
I keep an unsigned counter which is decremented by the timer ISR; if(tmr){tmr--;} stops it from rolling under. An unsigned char is sufficient for times up to 1 minute.
The main code can then set a variable preset value, making the timeout adjustable if needed and any specific event (eg keypress) can set the counter back to its preset.
When the counter expires I jump to a routine that shuts down the peripherals (as needed) and goes to sleep, then wakes up, restarts everything and returns.
This timer can be used for other things. 4Hz is a good rate for things like screen updates that aren't too fast or slow or for flashing LEDs etc. If needed, the counter timeout countdown can be displayed for the user by simply dividing by 4 or >>2.

how do you know that the unsigned char is sufficient for times up to 1 minute? if you have a 16 MHz oscillator, it would be 4/XTAL and if we want 30 seconds divided by (4/XTAL), then wouldn't the counter value be higher than what can be handled?

See my comment on the OP asking about the specific part you are using. Nearly all the parts I have used can apply a prescaler, count and postscaler to further divide down the clock; if the part you are using does not have these, then my answer probably does not apply to your scenario.
